# Access to the national vulnerability Database

Tags: java

I want to know How i can get access via java code to the National vulnerability Database (NVD)

(http://nvd.nist.gov/) is there any predefined functions.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I think there is no straigt way do to that. You have to find a way to reading an xml from the internet and extract the data by your self.

Comment: i want to have a direct access to the NVD  

so that I can use severity scores in my java application

these values ​​must be extracted directly from the NVD and not Stored locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They provide data feeds which you can find [here](http://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm)

Since it's regular RSS it should be easy to fetch it using Java

Comment: I want to make a link with the NVD so that,
if there will be a new vulnerability published, I should have it in real time

Comment: If it's a web app then just parse RSS and publish it. For desktop app just reload RSS every N minutes. They provide two up-to-date feeds: nvdcve-2.0-modified.xml - includes all recently published and recently updated vulnerabilities and 
nvdcve-2.0-recent.xml - includes all recently published vulnerabilities.

Comment: i haven't understand what do you mean exactly, please

Comment: i want exactly to extract a list of all vulnerability which are published By product name. and i have to use it in my application.

Comment: OK. They are providing the RSS feed and your task is to fetch it. If you want to track the changes in almost-real-time you need to implement it also by your own. I don't know what kind of app you are creating but as I said before for web apps just parse the feed in background and publish on your website, if you hit F5 it will reload the list. If you are creating standalone app (like desktop or so) you need to create some mechanism for fetching the feed every N time (like every hour or so). NVD offers only this way of accessing their data.

Comment: yes, i must capture the feed in real time, so that if there will be a new vulnerability published In the NVD, I should have it, in order to use its score. Now, the problem is if there is a way that enable me to have a list of vulnerability by product name. in other words, I must save a list of vulnerability for each product.

Comment: It's simply - transform the RSS schema to your own objects and present it as you want. In .NET there is Linq to RSS which simplifies such tasks but for Java it a little bit more complex. You can use product list (http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) then merge it with other feeds. Take a look on this project https://code.google.com/p/six-vuln/ maybe it will help.